# Combobox with dataset and bindingsource. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: .net, vb.net, binding, combobox, bindingsource

I have a datagridview and combobox on a form. I wish to move between rows of datagridview and combobox should be synchronized with the value of one of the columns of the dataset datagridview. In combobox I have a list with two possible values​​, Rational (1) and Irrational (2). The column "TYPE" of the dataset refers to previous types.
Below is the code, but not getting the desired result. What is wrong?

Thanks,
Davis

```
Public Class Form1
Private BdgSource As BindingSource = New BindingSource
Private StrCon As String = "Server=LOCALHOST:50000;Database=SAMPLE;UID=USERX;PWD=YYY;Connect Timeout=30"
Private Dts As DataSet = New DataSet

Private Class TypeAnimal
    Private _Type As Integer = 0
    Private _Desc As String = ""

    Property Type As Integer
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _Type = value
        End Set
        Get
            Return _Type
        End Get
    End Property

    Property Description As String
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Desc = value
        End Set
        Get
            Return _Desc
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal Type As Integer, ByVal Description As String)
        _Type = Type
        _Desc = Description
    End Sub

End Class

Private Sub UpdateDatagridView()
    Dim con As DB2Connection = New DB2Connection(StrCon)
    'Dim trans As DB2Transaction
    Dim cmd As DB2Command = New DB2Command
    Dim adp As DB2DataAdapter = New DB2DataAdapter

    con.Open()
    cmd.Transaction = con.BeginTransaction
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ANIMAL, TYPE FROM TESTE"
    'cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    adp.SelectCommand = cmd
    adp.Fill(Dts, "TABLE1")

    BdgSource.DataSource = Dts.Tables(0)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = BdgSource.DataSource

End Sub

Private Sub FillCombobox()
    Dim lista As List(Of TypeAnimal) = New List(Of TypeAnimal)

    lista.Add(New TypeAnimal(1, "Rational"))
    lista.Add(New TypeAnimal(2, "Irrational"))

    ComboBox1.DataSource = lista
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Description"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Type"

End Sub

Private Sub BindComponents()
    Dim bd As Binding = New Binding("SelectedValue", BdgSource, "TYPE")
    ComboBox1.DataBindings.Add(bd)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    UpdateDatagridView()
    FillCombobox()
    BindComponents()
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code should work well to **fill datagridview and combobox**

what else you want the code to do ?

what do you mean by (desired result) ,

***is it to change the combobox value when you change the selected row in datagridview ?***

if so . . . then you have to handle the ***SelectedIndexChanged***

Comment: Yes, that's the desired result, but changing to next row where the "TYPE" field has the 1 or 2 code the combobox doesn't display the current value  "Rational" or "Irrational".